# ColdFusion function variable naming with [ ] brackets

Tags: coldfusion

I've got a ColdFusion handler that is taking in 3 arguments one of which is a structure. The issue I'm facing is one of the variable name contains brackets which is an illegal character in the naming of a `cfargument`, see example.

```
chargifyResponse&id=123456&event=test&payload[chargify]=testing
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**Code**

```
<cffunction name="Webhook" access="remote" output="false">
    <cfargument name="id" required="false" type="string" />
    <cfargument name="event" required="false" type="string" />
    <cfargument name="payload&##91;chargify&##93;" required="false" type="any"/>
```

...

**Error**

Attribute validation error for CFARGUMENT.

The value of the NAME attribute is invalid.

Comment: Actually, cfargument has nothing to do with it.  It's the rules about variable names that are relevant.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fd3.html.  What is generating the url variables?

Comment: Hey @DanBracuk, I'm interacting with an API webhook so I don't have any control over the names.

Comment: You'll probably have to escape the characters. 
`chargifyResponse&id=123456&event=test&payload&#91;chargify&#93;=testing`. Or perhaps serialize the entire thing.

Comment: You do have one variable that might help  - `cgi.query_string`.

Comment: could you post the actual code that is having the issue?

Comment: Hey @Rado, I've updated with the code.

Comment: Hey @Jules, I tried taking those values but it's still giving me the same error

Comment: A messy solution is to replace the brackets with other (safe) characters. Then replace them back later.